# How to add custom arrow buttons to Alice-Carousel?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, carousel

I am making a carousel component with alice-carousel (https://github.com/maxmarinich/react-alice-carousel/blob/master/README.md) but having trouble customising the arrows. Code as follows

```
export const Carousel: React.FC<CarouselProps> = ({text }) => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);

  const items = ["item1","item2","item3"]


  const slidePrev = () => {
    activeIndex==0?(
      setActiveIndex(items.length-1)):
    setActiveIndex(activeIndex - 2);
            };

  const slideNext = () => {
    activeIndex==items.length-1?(
      setActiveIndex(0))
        : setActiveIndex(activeIndex + 2)

  };


return(
  <div className="grid grid-cols-3">
    <div className="col-span-2>
    {text}
    </div>
  <div className="flex justify-end">
            <button className="px-8" onClick={slidePrev}><ArrowL/></button>
            <button className="px-8" onClick={slideNext}><ArrowR/></button>
        </div>
<div className="col-span-3 px-10">
    <AliceCarousel
        mouseTracking
        disableDotsControls
        disableButtonsControls
        activeIndex={activeIndex}
        items={items}
        responsive={responsive}
        controlsStrategy="responsive"
        autoPlay={true}
        autoPlayInterval={5000}
        infinite={true}
        keyboardNavigation={true}

    />
    </div>
    </div>

)}
```

Above code changes the `activeIndex` therefore changing the items display order but it does so without the "slide" animation. I've looked at examples provided in the library used however cant seem to get it to slide smoothly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I encourage you to use the library's options to reduce the complexity of your implementation and stop unwanted behavior.

According to the documentation, there are two functions `renderPrevButton` and `renderNextButton` with the `AliceCarousel` to render your custom component (any elements, icons, buttons, ...) for the **Prev** and **Next** item on the gallery.

So, instead of defining a custom button with a custom action handler, pass your desired component to the mentioned function and give them some styles for customization.

```
export const Carousel: React.FC<CarouselProps> = ({text}) => {

  const items = ["item1","item2","item3"]

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-3">
      <div className="col-span-2">   // ---> you forgot to add closing string quotation mark
        {text}
      </div>
      <div className="col-span-3 px-10">
        <AliceCarousel
          mouseTracking
          disableDotsControls
          // disableButtonsControls  // ---> also remove this
          // activeIndex={activeIndex}  // ---> no need to this anymore
          items={items}
          responsive={responsive}
          controlsStrategy="responsive"
          autoPlay={true}
          autoPlayInterval={5000}
          infinite={true}
          keyboardNavigation={true}
          renderPrevButton={() => {
            return <p className="p-4 absolute left-0 top-0">Previous Item</p>
          }}
          renderNextButton={() => {
            return <p className="p-4 absolute right-0 top-0">Next Item</p>
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

**Note:** you need to remove the `disableButtonsControls` option from the `AliceCarousel` to handle the custom buttons properly. also, you don't need to use the `activeIndex` option anymore since the carousel will handle them automatically.

As a sample, I passed a `p` element with my `renderPrevButton` without any `onClick` action. you can define your custom icon, image, or any element and passed them.

Comment: thank you for your answer. However it doesn't seem to display the icon or the element i pass on as ```  renderPrevButton={() => {  <div><ArrowL/></div>}}```
I'm also wanting to customise where these controls are located(top right above the slider).

Comment: Yes, you can pass your custom element with the `renderPrevButton` and `renderNextButton` . you can style them as a usual component, in my example, I used the `absolute` property with `top-0` and `left-0` to add the `prevButton` in the top of the carousel, you can change it simply. @Dworo

Comment: I tried your code provided but did not show any of the elements/buttons or text added. Any reasons why?

Comment: did you remove the "disableButtonsControls" and "activeIndex" property from the `AliceCarousel` @Dworo ?

Comment: sure did. Is there a way i could call renderPrevButton/renderNextButton from the component outside of it?. Maybe something like `const slidePrev = () => {
    **method to call renderPrevButton**
            };`? 
Are react hooks/refs of any use here?
also if it's worth  noting the keyboard left & right arrow keys trigger the same too. Even a method that manually fires a keyboard button press event on the mouseClick?

Comment: `renderPrevButton={( )=>{return <ArrowL />}}` worked in the end

Comment: marking as correct answer as it was correct guidance

Answer (score 0):

For the `renderNextButton` and the `renderPrevButton` you have to declare a function first, then pass that function to the render option of the Alice Carousel.

```js
import ArrowBackIosIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBackIos';
import ArrowForwardIosIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowForwardIos';


export const Carousel: React.FC<CarouselProps> = ({text}) => {

  const items = ["item1","item2","item3"]
  
  const renderNextButton = ({ isDisabled }) => {
    return <ArrowForwardIosIcon style={{ position: "absolute", right: 0, top: 0 }} />
  };

  const renderPrevButton = ({ isDisabled }) => {
    return <ArrowBackIosIcon style={{ position: "absolute", left: 0, top: 0 }} />
  };

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-3">
      <div className="col-span-2">   // ---> you forgot to add closing string quotation mark
        {text}
      </div>
      <div className="col-span-3 px-10">
        <AliceCarousel
          mouseTracking
          disableDotsControls
          // disableButtonsControls  // ---> also remove this
          // activeIndex={activeIndex}  // ---> no need to this anymore
          items={items}
          responsive={responsive}
          controlsStrategy="responsive"
          autoPlay={true}
          autoPlayInterval={5000}
          infinite={true}
          keyboardNavigation={true}
          renderPrevButton={renderPrevButton}
          renderNextButton={renderNextButton}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```